# zsh history shows current time for old command

Tags: zsh, command-history

Somehow my zsh history shows wrong timestamps like this.

```
❯ history -E 1 | tail -20
 6047  31.12.2019 15:08  babel-node
 6048  31.12.2019 15:08  node -v
 6049  31.12.2019 15:08  git diff
 6050  31.12.2019 15:08  rm package-lock.json
 6051  31.12.2019 15:08  yarn update
 6052  31.12.2019 15:08  yarn
 6053  31.12.2019 15:08  rm yarn.lock
 6054  31.12.2019 15:08  yarn install
 6055  31.12.2019 15:08  yarn serve
 6056  31.12.2019 15:08  exit
 6058  31.12.2019 15:00  bin/rails s
 6059  31.12.2019 15:00  cd ../my_project
 6060  31.12.2019 15:00  bin/rails c
 6062  31.12.2019 15:03  man history
 6063  31.12.2019 15:03  vi ~/.bash_history
 6064  31.12.2019 15:03  vi ~/.zsh_history
 6065  31.12.2019 15:04  zsh -f
 6066  31.12.2019 15:06  fc -li 100
 6067  31.12.2019 15:08  history -E 1 | tail -100
```

All command those timesstamps `15:08` except the latest `history` command are executed before yesterday. The timestamps for old commands refresh every time `history` command is executed.

Though I'm going to clear history data, I don't want to encounter the same bug. Does anyone know what causes this error and how to prevent it?

I'm using `zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0)` in `iTerm2`.

### variables

These are my hist related variables.

```
❯ env | grep HIST

❯ typeset | grep HIST
HISTCHARS='!^#'
integer 10 readonly HISTCMD=6119
HISTFILE=/Users/ironsand/.zsh_history
integer 10 HISTSIZE=10000
integer 10 SAVEHIST=10000
```

Comment: What `*HIST*` variables (and related options) have you set in your shell, and to what values?

Comment: I added variables probably related to `history` command.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` shell option set in `zsh`, then the history events that are saved to `$HISTFILE` will be saved without timestamps.

When you use `history -E 1`, the history events are printed from the start of the in-memory history to the end, with timestamps (formatted in a particular way).

History entries that were read from `$HISTFILE` don't have timestamps, so they are assigned the timestamp corresponding to the time when the `history` command was executed.

To save timestamps with each history event, enable the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` shell option.  To do this for all future interactive `zsh` shell session, modify your `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc` file and add

```
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
```